# java ThreadPool race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code, I have a large loop that I want to run in parallel. Unfortunately a race condition exists, in some cases (not all, not predictable) I get blocked at `s.awaitTermination`. There is no thread synchronization except at the end where I remove the finished thread from the set, and if the set is empty call `shutdown`. Where am I going wrong? FYI thousands of tasks get added to the queue, I don't want them all trying to run at once, is there a better pattern than this?

When I check the queue, it has tasks left, and the pool threads are "parked at unsafe...." according to Netbeans debug.

EDIT: updating `Thread` to `Runnable` as suggested - did not fix the problem

```
ExecutorService s = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
final Set<Runnable> threads = new HashSet<>();
for(/*lots of loops*/){
  Runnable t = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      //some long task...
      synchronized(threads){
        threads.remove(this);
        if(threads.isEmpty()){
          s.shutdown();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

synchronized(threads){
  for(Runnable t : threads){
    s.submit(t);
  }
}

s.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Why do you submit `Thread`s as `Runnable`s? Don't create `Thread` anonymous classes, create `Runnable` ones.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _get blocked at [...]_? It shouldn't block for more than 1000 seconds.

Comment: Yes, it releases after 1000s, but the task should take at most 1 min (it typically does). The Thread vs Runnable was because initially I was using threads, I made that change, but it still doesnt run (will update code)

Comment: How many threads (runnables) do you have, and how long is "some long task"?

Comment: @Andreas, it changes - in the worst observed case 2000 tasks of which at least 1000 complete, "some long task" is iterating over approximately 3000 (worst case) items, comparing them to some known value and updating a matrix based on that. e.g. I have a 2000x3000 matrix where I need to look at each item and update a second matrix accordingly

Comment: So how do you know the job can be completed in 16 minutes? Anyway, try to add some logging/printing statements to see progress, e.g. log before submit loop, before await call, at beginning of `run()` and log size of `threads` after removing an entry. The two logs produced inside `run()` should include a unique identifiable value, using `this.hashCode()` if nothing else is appropriate.

Comment: @Andreas, I've run the same task before on the same input, it's usually quite quick, way less than the 16 min timeout.

Comment: Is it possible one of the threads is getting an exception, which you're not catching correctly? This would then cause the set to never get emptied, and the whole system to hang.

Comment: I'd still like to know why the error existed, but I accepted a solution that allowed me to continue

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, no exception in logs, and the code has nothing that I would expect to cause a bug - definitely not a transient one. It literally just pulls a value from the matrix and sets the same value in another matrix, so null pointer or array index exceptions could occur, but neither of those would *sometimes* occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not is a solution for your question, but it might help you to do the same task easily. Take a look at the [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) it can execute multiple tasks and it will return you a future that you can use to wait. Internally it uses a queue for the completed tasks so basically accomplished what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Very nice solution - I was hoping something cleaner than my attempt would exst.